# How do I display the Indian regional languages properly in tablets or non Indian Mobiles

Tags: android

I need to display text in all the regional languages in an Android application. I am able to display in indian Android mobiles using ttf font files. But I am not able to display properly in non indian android mobiles and in emulator. I want to display properly in non indian mobiles, so please suggest me how to resolve this issue.

Comment: Using an external font should have fixed this. How are you doing it?

Comment: There is a rendering issue for all indian languages in non-indian market mobiles and emulators for Android versions less than Jelly bean. In Jellybean, rendering of Indian languages are fine as it supports the indian languages. I want to know to display the indian languages with proper rendering in Android versions less than Jelly bean? I have seen some apps with proper rendering even for earlier Android versions in Google Store. Any suggestions would be welcome. Thanks.